# though setting keyExtractor, I'm getting VirtualizedList: missing keys for items, make sure to specify a key or provide a custom keyExtractor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, rest

I've set a custom Key extractor for the orders items in the cart, also getting VirtualizedList: missing keys for items, make sure to specify a key or id property on each item or provide a custom key extractor.

Here is code for the orders page.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback} from "react"
import { View, FlatList, Text} from "react-native"
import axios from "axios"
import baseURL from "../../assets/common/baseUrl"
import { useFocusEffect } from "@react-navigation/native"

import OrderCard from "../../Shared/OrderCard"


const Orders = (props) => {

    const [orderList, setOrderList] = useState();

    useFocusEffect(
        useCallback(
            () => {
                getOrders();
            return () => {
                setOrderList();
            }
            },
            [],
        )
    )


    const getOrders = () => {
        axios
        .get(`${baseURL}orders`)
        .then((x) => {
            setOrderList(x.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <FlatList 
                data={orderList}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <OrderCard navigation={props.navigation} {...item} editMode={true}/>
                )}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
        </View>
    )
}

export default Orders;
```

After placing the orders by adding item to the cart,
[image]

There is no error shown or pop up in the mobile app,
[image]

The error is shown in the console where the react-native app is run

```
VirtualizedList: missing keys for items, make sure to specify a key or id property on each item or provide a custom keyExtractor.,
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:117:10 in registerWarning
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:63:8 in warnImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:36:4 in console.warn
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:18:4 in warn
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Lists\VirtualizedList.js:1075:8 in render
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12479:21 in finishClassComponent
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12404:43 in updateClassComponent
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19182:22 in beginWork$1
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18086:22 in performUnitOfWork
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18014:38 in workLoopSync
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17978:18 in renderRootSync
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17675:33 in performSyncWorkOnRoot
at [native code]:null in performSyncWorkOnRoot
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5322:31 in runWithPriority$argument_1at node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:653:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5317:21 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImplat node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5305:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17719:28 in batchedUpdates$1
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2492:29 in batchedUpdates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2638:16 in _receiveRootNodeIDEvent
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2767:27 in receiveTouches
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Here is the picture for it
[image]

Comment: Hello, can you give an example of what is in orderList?

Comment: I have a key extractor in 3 files, for the category, orders and product, I exactly don't get it in which file the error is located

Comment: I was asking for an example of value for orderList the variable you give to your flatlist.

Comment: I think the error is located in my cart.js file where I've not set keyExtractor.Here is my code for the cart.js https://github.com/Hardikpoudel/pasal/blob/pic/Screens/Cart/Cart.js inline 44 of the code